# Spring Security "authorities-by-username-query" error

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring

i am trying to write **query** for **authorization** using spring security

i have **User Groups (eg. admin,User)** and each UserGrups have **rights(prog_read,prog_write)**
 & users are mapped with user Groups

i am trying to write query which gives me User names and there rights which are required.

`SELECT DISTINCT
    ug.USERNAME, gr.grupRights
from
    gruprights gr,
    usergrups ug
where
    ugm.grupName = grm.grupName and ug.USERNAME=? and gr.grupName  in (select 
            grupName
        from
            usergrups
        where
            USERNAME = ?);`

i am getting error:

> nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for
>   parameter 2

i am using **authorities-by-username-query**  in spring-security.xml

Answer (score 1):

Which means that the query expects 2 arguments(I see two ? in query) but you are specifying only one. You need to pass `username` twice

Comment: i am not even passing first parameter ,as it is passed by spring authorities-by-username-query tag

Comment: you either should pass 2 arguments or ur query must be wrong.

Comment: query is working fine when i hardcode username in query,but it's not working  in spring-security.xml using authorities-by-username-query

Comment: Ahh... now I see it, The problem is that spring security expects that the users-by-username-query and authorities-by-username-query have a single parameter (username) so if your query contain two parameters like

username = ? and email = ? or in your case username = ? and username = ?

the query will fail.

Comment: What you can do, is to implement your own UserDetailsService that will perform the query (or queries) to search user... if not modify the query such that it takes only one parameter.